# Ruby on rails formatting number

Tags: ruby

I want a number to be printed like "42/100". This formatting should be done by a function which I am gonna use in two different models. where should I add that method?

Comment: Why is it "/100"?

Comment: What is user_database.rb?

Comment: If you want a method in multiple classes, you can define it in a module and include the module in each class. http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html

Comment: @SimpleLime  it's out of 100. And yes in future it might change

Comment: @JagdeepSingh sorry my bad edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as per the limited description, here is what i propose:

*formatting_helper.rb*

```
module FormattingHelper
  MAXIMUM_VALUE = 100.freeze   # Change it here.

  def self.divide_by_maximum_value(str)
    "#{str}/#{MAXIMUM_VALUE}"
  end
end
```

And then you will be able to call `FormattingHelper.divide_by_maximum_value` from anywhere. e.g.

```
FormattingHelper.divide_by_maximum_value('42')
 => "42/100"
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a very silly question but as am new dont know how to do it and can you please tell me what happen if I define those methods in application_helper.

Comment: ApplicationHelper methods will be available in your views. But it seems you need them to be called in your model and some service user_database.rb. So, you will have to define a separate mixin here. Somewhere at /app/mixins/formatting_helper.rb.

Comment: in this case I could also put `"A"` over 100 which seems odd. Maybe use the [`Rational`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Rational.html) class instead? e.g. `Rational.new(str,MAXIMUM_VALUE).to_s`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a number to percentage you can use
[number helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) from ruby on rails official guide

```
    number_to_percentage(42)                                        
    # => 42.000%
```

except those guide, you should create module like jagdeep singth said.
or create lambda

```
    num_formatter = ->(x,y='100') {  x.to_s+"/#{y.to_s}"  }
    num_formatter.call(42)
    # => "42/100"
    num_formatter.call(42,1000)
    # => "42/1000"
```

Comment: "100" is expected to change in future.

Comment: just add the y value @JagdeepSingh